# How can I fix this? Blender Mesh Problem

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects, vertices

I've been following the Blender Guru Donut tutorial and this keeps happening.My two meshes intervene with each other in edit mode but in object mode it all seems fine. [image]Can anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: You've hidden the solidify modifier in edit mode.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case it is not clear to you how to "unhide" "the solidify modifier in edit mode"
I am adding an screen shot to illustrate Robert's comment. :)
[image]